# MS SQL Server differentiate system and user defined indexes using sys.indexes table

Tags: sql-server, index, system-tables

I am trying to write a sproc to maintain all the indexes created by me.
[image]

My indexes are shown in random numbered rows in sys.indexes table, mixed with system indexes. Now I want to write a select statement to choose only indexes created by me.
(like I can do for databases 'where database_id > 4' in sys.databases)
Here, index_id has different meaning and is not unique.
Can someone help me?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: see this will help you https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/exploring-your-database-schema-with-sql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a way to select all the indexes of user defined tables

```
select 
   idx.[name] as [Index]
from sys.indexes as idx
inner join sys.objects as obj on idx.object_id = obj.object_id
where idx.[name] is not null and obj.[type] = 'u'
order by idx.[name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are up to, but if you're wanting generic maintenance scripts then you can't go wrong with https://ola.hallengren.com/. I'm sure they could be tailored to your precise requirements.